# C++ Floating Point Addition (from scratch): Negative results cannot be computed

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, floating-point

I am implementing a floating point addition program **from scratch**, following the methodology listed out in this PDF: [https://www.cs.colostate.edu/~cs270/.Fall20/resources/FloatingPointExample.pdf](https://www.cs.colostate.edu/%7Ecs270/.Fall20/resources/FloatingPointExample.pdf)

The main issue I am having is that addition works when the result is positive (e.x. -10 + 12,  3 + 5.125), but the addition does not work when the result is negative. This is because do not understand how to implement the following step:

```
Step 5: Convert result from 2’s complement to signed magnitude
If the result is negative, convert the mantissa back to signed magnitude by inverting the bits and adding 1. The result is
positive in this example, so nothing needs to be done.
```

How do I determine if the result is negative without using floating point addition (I am not allowed to use any floating or double adds)? Of course I can see if the current and the next floats are negative and see their cumulative quantities, but that would defeat the purposes of this assignment.

If given **only** the following:

1. Sign bit, exponent, and mantissa of X
2. Sign bit, exponent, and mantissa of Y
3. Mantissa and exponent of Z

How do I determine whether `Z = X + Y` is negative just with the above data and not using any floating point addition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At step 5, you’ve already added the mantissas. To determine whether the result is positive  or negative, just check the sign bit of that sum.

Comment: Q: How do I do X? A: Just do X. If it's that simple, maybe OP is missing a detail or you are. In both cases, this answer would require a bit more explanation.

Comment: When you say check the sign bit of the sum, do you mean checking the sign bit of the mantissa? The sign bit of Z is still its default value at step 5.

Comment: Yes, of the mantissa. That entirely determines the sign of the result.

Answer (score 3):

The key insight is that many floating-point formats keep the sign and mantissa separate, so the mantissa is an **unsigned** integer. The sign and mantissa can be trivially combined to create a **signed** integer. You can then use signed integer arithmetic to add or subtract the two mantissa's of your floating-point number.

Answer (score 2):

If you are following the PDF you posted, you should have converted the numbers to 2's complement at **Step 3**. After the addition in **Step 4**, you have the result  in 2's complement. (Result of adding the shifted numbers)

To check if the result is negative, you need to check the leftmost bit (the sign bit) in the resulting bit pattern. In 2's complement, this bit is 1 for negative numbers, and 0 for nonnegative numbers.

```cpp
sign = signBit;
if (signBit) {
  result = ~result + 1;
}
```

If you are using unsigned integers to hold the bit pattern, you could make them of a fixed size, so that you are able to find the sign bit using shifts later.

```cpp
uint64_t result;
...
signBit = (result >> 63) & 1;
```

Comment: `result = ~result + 1;` Why would you ever write that instead of `result = -result;`?  In the C with signed integers, you're logically dealing with values, not bit-patterns.  If you write it correctly (using unary `-`), it will even work on C implementations that use one's complement.  At least this part of it; it would certainly less convenient to have to use `unsigned` to get 2's complement addition / subtraction because IEEE-754 formats after unbiasing the exponent have basically a 2's complement signed exponent.

Comment: Since the document in the question suggested turning the numbers to 2's complement, I considered the integers, or whatever we are using to hold the resulting pattern, simply as an object that we use to hold the bit pattern corresponding to the 2's complement representation. If you negated the numbers with a minus at the first place, than you would certainly need to account for any representation that the system is allowed to use. In that case, a - would be the correct way to go.

Comment: The second one isn't even real code, it is just there to show that you need to convert back to positive numbers.

Comment: I see your point now, comparing with 0 was wrong. Updated the answer.

Comment: If you want to just work with bit-patterns not values, you *should* use unsigned, and then `result = -result;` does the right thing in C.  C guarantees that unsigned integers are binary and wrap normally (the same was as 2's complement).  There's just no reason to bust out a 2's complement identity to do negation.  If you `result` is signed, and you care about portability to C implementations that don't use 2's complement, I don't think it's safe to use signed `+ 1` which might be one's complement or sign/magnitude.  Or `~` which is one's complement negation (equiv to `-result`).

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between grade school math and what we do with floating point is that we have twos complement (base 2 vs base 10 is not really relevant, just makes life easier).  So if you made it through grade school you know how all of this works.

In decimal in grade school you align the decimal points and then do the math. With floating point we shift the smaller number and discard it's mantissa (sorry fraction) bits to line it up with the larger number.

In grade school if doing subtraction you subtract the smaller number from the larger number once you resolve the identities

```
a - (-b) = a + b
-a + b = b - a
```

and so on so that you either have

```
n - m
```

or

```
n + m
```

And then you do the math.  Apply the sign based on what you had to do to get a-b or a+b.

The beauty of twos complement is that a negation or negative is invert and add one, which feeds nicely into logic.

```
a - b = a + (-b) = a + (~b) + 1
```

so you do not re-arrange the operands but you might have to negate the second one.
Also you do not have to remember the sign of the result the result tells you its
sign.

So align the points
put it in the form

```
a + b  
a + (-b)
```

Where a can be positive or negative but b's sign and the operation may need to
negate b.

Do the addition.

If the result is negative, negate the result into a positive

Normalize

IEEE is only involved in the desire to have the 1.fraction be positive, other floating point formats allow for negative whole.fraction and do not negate, simply
normalize.  The rest of it is just grade school math (plus twos complement)

Some examples

---

```
2 + 4
```

in binary the numbers are

```
+10
+100
```

which converted to a normalized form are

```
+1.0  * 2^1
+1.00 * 2^2
```

need same exponent (align the point)

```
+0.10 * 2^2
+1.00 * 2^2
```

both are positive so no change just do the addition

this is the base form, I put more sign extension out front than needed
to make the sign of the result much easier to see.

```
      0
 000010
+000100
=======
```

fill it in

```
 000000
 000010
+000100
========
 000110
```

result is positive (msbit of result is zero) so normalize

```
+1.10 * 2^2
```

---

```
4+5

100
101

+1.00 2^2
+1.01 2^2
```

same exponent
both positive

```
      0
 000100
+000101
=======

 001000
 000100
+000101
=======
 001001
```

result is positive so  normalize

```
+1.001 * 2^3
```

---

```
4 - 2

100
10

+1.00 * 2^2
+1.0  * 2^1
```

need the same exponent

```
+1.00 * 2^2
+0.10 * 2^2
```

subtract a - b = a + (-b)

```
     1 <--- add one
 00100
+11101 <--- invert
=======
```

fill it in

```
 11011
 00100
+11101
=======
 00010
```

result is positive so normalize

```
+1.0 * 2^1
```

---

```
2 - 4

10
100

+1.0 * 2^1
+1.00 * 2^2
```

make same exponent

```
+0.10 * 2^2
+1.00 * 2^2
```

do the math

```
a - b = a + (-b)

      1
 000010
+111011
========
```

fill it in

```
 000111
 000010
+111011
========
 111110
```

result is negative so negate (0 - n)

```
 000011  <--- add one  
 000000
+000001  <--- invert
=========
 000010
```

normalize

```
-1.0 * 2^1
```